# Django : meaning of {% url 'zzz' %}?{{ yyy }}?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, href

I came across a code in a HTML file and I did not understand how it works.

```
{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}
```

Especially, what does the "?" mean? And how is the code interpreted?

It is used in a button to switch between month but I cant figure out how it works.

I tried to print different places in the code to see what is executed with but I did not find anything interesting.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Especially, what does the "?" mean?

This is for the [*query string* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Indeed, if for example `prev_month` contains `foo`, it will make a query that looks like:

```
/some/path?foo
```

The querystring is a key-value dictionary where the same key can map to multiple values. You can access this with [**`request.GET`** <sup>[django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET). Usually it is thus provided, for example as:

```
/some/path?foo=bar
```

If you use the item as value, you should work with the [**`|urlencode`** template filter <sup>[django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode):

```
{% url 'calendar' %}?month={{ prev_month|urlencode }}
```

If the `prev_month` then for example itself contains a question mark (`?`), ampersand (`&`), etc. that will be escaped properly.